# how azure search treat string like "Good Phase" To search on cloud db

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I need technical help regarding my Azure document search

below my sample code

`var searchText = "Good Phase"

var searchData = indexClient.Documents.Search(searchText,searchParameters)`

I need to know this document search which is  searchText = "Good Phase"

how azure document treat this "Good Phase" to search

means like

1:- Good AND Phase (with AND operator)

2:- Good OR Phase (With OR Operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When searching text such as “Good phase”, the search text is tokenized so that your terms will be separated by white space to two terms: “Good” and “phase” and the search results will be either term.
If you want all the terms to match you can specify searchmode=all, the default value is any.

More details you can find here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents
And also another good source: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture
which explains how full text search works in Azure Search.

Thanks!

Comment: And it means it search as or like fatch all data which is Good , phase ?

Answer (score 0):

**here is link answer by Mr Liam Cavanagh**

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/2eb93403-afc5-4d99-a1c8-2e29ca6026a5/azure-document-search-default-nature-for-searching-text-on-azure-db?forum=azuresearch